# Django подкатегории

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-filter

Подскажите правильно ли я делаю?
в итоге должно получиться чтото вроде Техника-- > Для дома --Мониторы.
Для начала создаю в админке категорию без парента Техника, после создаю категорию Для дома с парентом техника и после создаю категорию Мониторы с парентом Для дома, и как это можно сделать на 1 странице в админке при создании категории чтоб можно было туда и подкатегории приписывать?

```py
class BaseView(CartMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        main_category = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
        subcategory = Category.objects.exclude(parent_category=None)
        
        products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:8]
        myimage = MyImage.objects.all()
        random_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')[:10]
        form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)

        context = {
            'main_category': main_category,
            'subcategory': subcategory,
            'products': products,
            'cart': self.cart,
            'myimage': myimage,
            'randomProducts': random_products,
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

категория и подкатегория выводятся правильно , а как обратиться к подкатегории подкатегории?

```html
{% for category in main_category %}

    <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children has-mega-menu"><a href="#">{{category}}
    </a>   

      <div class="mega-menu">
        <div class="mega-wrap">
          <div class="mega-column">
            <ul class="mega-item mega-features">
  
              <li><a href="product-listing.html">{{category.brand}}</a></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="mega-column">

            {% for subcategories in subcategory %}
            {% if subcategories.parent_category.id == category.id %}

            <h4 class="mega-heading">{{subcategories}}</h4>{% endif %}
            <ul class="mega-item">
              {% if subcategories.parent_category.id == category.id %}

              <li><a href="product-listing.html">{{subcategories}}</a></li>{% endif %}

            </ul>         
               {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    {%endfor%}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: что, если субсубкатегории установить родителем субкатегорию, а потом отдать словарем вида 'categories: {
 'cat_1': {
  'subcat1': {},
  'subcat2': {
   'subsubcat1',
   'subsubcat2',
   'subsubcat3'
  },
  'subcat3': {}
 }
}'

и отрендерить
'{% for cat in categories %}
 {{cat}}
 {% for subcat in cat %}
  {{subcat}}
  {% for subsubcat in subcat %}
   {{subsubcat}}'

Comment: как тогда запрос сделать что бы получить subcat1.subcat2 и тд?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730771/django-category-list-parent-child

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769707/python-django-recursive-model-into-tree-structrue-dict

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37626867/django-most-efficient-way-to-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-querying-related-m